# Functional testing MissingMandatoryParametersException if locale in my route

Tags: php, symfony, phpunit, functional-testing

I call a method of my API by its name from a specific test through `phpunit` and I'm having this error:

> exception
>
> 'Symfony\Component\Routing\Exception\MissingMandatoryParametersException'
>   with message 'Some mandatory parameters are missing ("_locale") to
>   generate a URL for route "some_route" in ...
>
> src\Symfony\Component\Routing\Generator\UrlGenerator.php:155

When the method I'm calling from my test call `generate` of `Router`

Given that I'm using this technique http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/testing/simulating_authentication.html to authenticate but without `Client` cause I don't need to request URLs. I'm just having my `$kernel = static::createKernel(....`

> And here is my routing.yml

```
some_route:
   pattern: /{_locale}/id
   default: { _controller: myBundle:myController:myAction }
```

Do you know how do I fix it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Do you know how do I fix it ?

Pass a value for the `_locale` parameter (which is in your route and does not have a default value) when generating the route using `Router#generate()`.

Btw, be aware that it is not considered a good practice if you use `Router#generate()` in your tests to generate the route to access, use static strings instead.

Comment: The method calling `Router#generate()` is a method of a service